# Will water introduced in a large tube connected to a small tube force water upward

Tags: pressure, water

Will water introduced in a large tube connected to a small tube force water upward as a self starting siphon. I am thinking of a 3"pvc pipe 6" long sealed with only a 3/8 tube coming out of it will create excess pressure 3" pushing the water up the 3/8" tube 2 feet

Answer (score 1):

No,  the water will be at the same level in both tubes.  Hydrostatic pressure depends only on the height of the liquid and not the area of the tube. Remember that pressure is force  per unit area.  The weight of liquid in the thin tube is less than that of the liquid  in the thick tube.  By a factor of 8. But the area of the tube is also smaller by a factor of 8. So the two pressures are equal for equal heights.